# C++ Pass different arrays of different sizes to same function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 3 2D arrays that I wanted to pass to a function. Currently, I use if-else statement to decide which array to be sent then copy the selected array's content and pass the new array.

new array:

```
char board[100][100]={}
```

these are the arrays(content not shown):

```
char mazeEasy[19][38], mazeMed[41][81], mazeHard[72][98];
```

How can I pass either one of these three to one function without using `board[100][100]`?

Comment: Simple answer is that you cannot. Use std::vector instead of 2D arrays

Comment: @evilruff No that doesn't work. seems lots of people doesn't understand 2D arrays.

Comment: @evilruff Sorry to labour the point but neither char* or char** work. The point is that 2D arrays of different sizes are laid out differently internally. You cannot write a single function to deal with different sized 2D arrays unless you use templates.

Comment: @evilruff Your code is making assumptions about the internal layout of a 2D array. Those assumptions might not be correct on another compiler. But now I say that I'm not 100% confident. Write up your code as an answer if you feel it might be useful.

Comment: @evilruff Seems I was wrong. Apologies. I would definitely write up your answer.

Comment: @john No probs at all, moved discussion into separate answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possibility would be a `template` function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim1, std::size_t Dim2>
void f(T(&)[Dim1][Dim2])
{
    std::cout << Dim1 << ", " << Dim2 << "\n";
}
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/b60h1e . Note this will instantiate three different instances of the function template (one instantiation for every different combination of dimensions).

Recommend changing to a [`std::vector<std::vector<char>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. This avoids the multiple instantiations and the function can query the `std::vector` for its size or iterate:

```
void f(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& a_maze)
{
    std::cout << a_maze.size() << ", " << a_maze[0].size() << "\n";
}
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/nHL8Hj .

Comment: The demo helps a lot. Still not clear on vectors but using it seems better.

Answer (score 3):

Not to the *same* function, but you can get a function per pair of dimensions by using templates and the relatively unknown "pass an array by reference if you want explicit dimensions" method:

```
template<size_t i, size_t j>
void stuff(char (&arr)[i][j])
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < j; y++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[x][y] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

/Moved from comments/

Correct me if I am wrong but I believe that memory layout of 2D array in C is part of the standard and you cannot expect anything rather that

```
 An object of array type contains a contiguously allocated non-empty 
 set of N sub-objects of type T.
```

Same applied for 2D.

So I would propose simplified C-style solution. Life is not over on modern C++ compilers, sometimes you need similar solutions for light-wighted embedded systems and compilers.

```
void dumpArray( int * array, int w, int h) 
{ 
    for (int i=0;i<h;i++) 
      for (int j=0;j<w;j++) 
        { 
          printf("[%i,%i] = %i\n", i,j,array[i*w+j]); 
        } 
} 

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{ 
     int a[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }; 
     int a1[3][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} }; 

     dumpArray( (int*)a, 3, 2); 
     dumpArray( (int*)a1, 3, 3); 
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Doing this give me `error: invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript`

Comment: which line? did you compile my code or build your own based on my idea?

Comment: Your code works fine but I cannot implement it in mine. I did exactly like the above except that my arrays are `char` and I don't have `int argc, char * argv[]`. Is that the reason?

Comment: 1) dumpArray( char * array, int w, int h); 2) dumpArray( (char*)a, h, w);